# C# Passing Data from form2 to form3

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a field farm software. There are 3 forms: *form1*, *form2*, *form3*.

*form1* is just a welcome page then when you proceed to *form2*, its a data collection, where inputs are collected from textboxes and then multiplied at background and displayed on *form3*.

Comment: And where is the code of this? What issue you are facing with that, code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is concentrating on solving concrete programming problems, not giving general programming advice. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its not a duplicate please... Read the tracks

Comment: the ppost that was flagged with duplicate is actually different

Comment: Read both questions

Answer (score 0):

The crude horrible way to do that is you could have on Form3, 14 different public facing properties.

```
public string textboxValue1;
public string textboxValue2;
public string textboxValue3;
etc...
```

Then when you new up Form3, you'll have access to these and pass the data that way.

so:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
form3.textboxValue1 = fieldValue1;
form3.textboxValue2 = fieldValue2;
form3.textboxValue3 = fieldValue3;
etc..
form3.ShowModal();
form3.Dispose();
```

Ideally you should be using a business object / model.
You've already mentioned 14 rows and 4 columns, so your model might look something like this:

```
public class modelname
{
  public datatype column1fieldname { get; set; }
  public datatype column2fieldname { get; set; }
  public datatype column3fieldname { get; set; }
  public datatype column4fieldname { get; set; }
}
```

where datatype is string, int, decimal or whatever value types your using, and column_n_fieldname relates to something sensible in your object!

On form2 you can have a private property:

```
private List<modelname> capturedData;
```

in the constructor - new it up so:

```
public Form2()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  capturedData = new List<modelname>();
}
```

when the user clicks to form3, you can stuff your data from the textboxes into the model -> then pass the model to form3 to do whatever you want with it.

so on form2 you might have a couple of methods like:

```
private void CollectData()
{
  capturedData.Clear();

  AddRowData(yourrow1column1value, yourrow1column2value, yourrow1column3value, yourrow1column4value);  // Row 1
  AddRowData(yourrow2column1value, yourrow2column2value, yourrow2column3value, yourrow2column4value);  // Row 2
  // etc...
}

private void AddRowData(datatype column1data, datatype column2data, datatype column3data, datatype column4data)
{
  capturedData.Add(new modelname() { column1fieldname = column1data, column2fieldname = column2data, column3fieldname = column3data, column4fieldname = column4data});
}
```

Form3's constructor might be:

```
public Form3(List<modelname> capturedData)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // Then whatever you want to do with it...
}
```

Comment: thanks but actually cant understand this

Comment: What bit don't you understand?  There are two solutions above... one horrible crude noob way to do what you want (first 2 code blocks), and one more technically correct using a business model (simply a class where you would store a row's piece of data), which you can then pass onto form 3 for it's manipulated view.  You could even pass this row into some business logic that converts the data into the manipulated view for you ready to pass onto form3.